# curious: where does git store user information?

Tags: git

I'm wondering where does git stores user information. I created a repository, which both me and my friend works on. When we both commit, we can see both of us as individual authors for different revisions. while theres a .gitconfig file created using `git config --global` in his home folder, I couldn't find one in mine. So where's my user information stored? Does `git config --global` only affect the individual login user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not store user information in your configuration files Git looks in the environment for committer information, using the variables `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`, `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, and `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`. In absence of these variables, your username and host name are used to construct a value. So even without any user information stored in configuration files two users will have different committer information.

Comment: This information (my email) gets public? When I commit to GitHub providing my email, does it become visible to anyone but GitHub servers?

Answer (score 32):

There are 3 default paths for the config file.

- Repository itself: `<your_git_repository>/.git/config`
- User home directory: `~/.gitconfig`
- System-wide directory: `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`

The `--global` option always use the home directory. Note that `git` will always try to read all of them. If it finds one, it loads it, and moves to the next one. Local takes precedence over global, which takes precedence over system-wide. It uses a simple key-merging algorithm.

Reference: [git-config FILES](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES)

Comment: strange, running find / -name gitconfig does not return me any results.

Comment: Do you have an env var GIT_CONFIG_LOCAL? Another possibility is cited by @Bombe in his answer.

Comment: @yair That's the prefix path specified during compilation. If you installed Git using a package manager (apt, yum, etc), it installs it globally with no prefix. If you use something like macports, brew, then it specifies a prefix like /usr/local or /opt/local. You can specify this prefix when you compile most softwares that use autotools.

Answer (score 6):

There are three places - system ( all users on the system at `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`), global ( for the user at `~/.gitconfig`) and local ( for the repo at `.git/config`). Any config should be in either of the three to be taken by git.

However if `GIT_CONFIG` or myriad other environment variable are set, some of the values will be coming from those. If you are not able to find what you want in any of the config files, or not even able to find these files, look at all GIT_* environment variables as the last resort.

More details here:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I found my username in the `~/.git-credentials` file.  Hope this helps you.
You can also list the configuration using:

```
git config --list
```