# How to List all folders (projects) of a Git Repository

Tags: java, git, egit

By using the cookbook examples, I am able to fetch the all folders (projects) under HEAD in a offline Git repository e.g.

```
String url = "C:/Users/kishore/git/JavaRepos/.git";

File gitDir = new File(url);
Repository repository = new FileRepository(gitDir);

Ref head = repository.getRef("HEAD");

RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);

RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
RevTree tree = commit.getTree();
System.out.println("Having tree: " + tree);

TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository);
treeWalk.addTree(tree);
treeWalk.setRecursive(false);
while(treeWalk.next()) {
    System.out.println("Folder Path: " + treeWalk.getPathString());
    System.out.println("Folder Name: " + treeWalk.getNameString());
    System.out.println("Folder depth: " + treeWalk.getDepth());
    System.out.println("Folder Tree Count: " + treeWalk.getTreeCount());
}
```

This code lists the all folders for a given Git repository url located on my machine But

```
Ref head = repository.getRef("HEAD");
```

line returning null for any online Git repository URL e.g. **https://github.com/github/testrepo.git**

What I am missing in the second case.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think authentication is the reason behind this.
Your code nowhere mentions username and password and while accessing remote git branches you need to provide your credentials.
Check if the available resources provide any way of authentication.

Comment: Why authentication is not required for cloning the same repository on _'Git Bash'_ command prompt i.e. **git clone https://github.com/github/testrepo.git**

Comment: This thread seems relevant to your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328826/curious-where-does-git-store-user-information

Comment: Thx @Mahesh. Yes I got some info about saving user authentication But how to do this in Java by using EGit(http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide) APIs.

Comment: I hope this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311857/jgit-connect-to-distant-repository

Comment: According to this post, User Authentication for remote repository is not possible by Java APIs. Then what should do in this case.

Comment: what is your purpose for doing this? May be there could be another way round. Are you doing this to test JGIT APIs or something else?

Comment: To provide support in my Java application for Git(http://git-scm.com) version control similar to SVN. But in SVN authentication can be given as  _org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.setAuthenticationManager()_. But how to do this in Git, don't know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35830/discussion-between-kishore-and-mahesh-gosemath)