# Git permission denied to default user

Tags: git, github

I am running two PCs running Windows 10 Pro x64. (Practically identical setups). 
I am running git version 2.12.2.windows.2 on both PCs.
My username is the same on both machines and they sit side-by-side and I use a virtual KVM to access both with one keyboard and mouse.

On PC1 I use git with my active GitHub account and I can successfully use git with no issues (related to this post).  I use 'username01' as the name on my GitHub account and 'username01@gmail.com' to successfully login.  FWIW, the location of my GitHub account has the same name as 'username01'.

On PC2 I try to use git with my active GitHub account and I cannot successfully interact with the same account information.  When I pull everything comes down fine.  However, when I try to commit, I receive the following error message:

```
***remote: Permission to username01/Test.git denied to username02***
```

NOTE: the denied to username02 is not a typo and that is my reason for posting this question.

For further clarification, I once had to interact with a different GitHub account using 'username02'.  I no longer wish to use 'username02', nor that other account, but I cannot determine where the 'username02' is stored in order to change it (or better purge it).

Also, my git config --list output on PC2 shows no sign of 'username02' and in fact, has the info for 'username01' stored.

I cannot find 'username02' anywhere in the settings for Git.

The 'username02' does not affect PC1 at all.  Does anyone know how I can purge 'username02' from PC2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the file `~/.gitconfig`, you'll probably find what you want here. After making your changes to the file, you can check it worked by issuing

```
git config user.email
```

[Further reading](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/).

Comment: Thanks cristianoms, but that was not a solution. The first username01 was in that file (alone).  That second user name is cached somewhere in Windows, but I cannot find it.  I ended up creating a new GitHub account for the (second) username02 and now I can use the new repository if necessary.

Comment: I did some more digging and discovered that git has other ways to store the username information: as environment variables (GIT_COMMITTER_NAME, GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL, GIT_AUTHOR_NAME, and GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL); in the repo itself under repo/.git/config; in the ~/.gitconfig file (as I said) and system wide, under $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig. More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328826/curious-where-does-git-store-user-information and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES